# float datatype getting changed to int in javascript

Tags: javascript

We have a very old JavaScript SDK(Built in core javascript) and making changes in this script in this SDK is very difficult.

We have this function in the script SDK.dispatch("action", value). This function has to be called by the client webiste, and they can pass any type of data to it. We have now a situation where the client is calling SDK.dispatch("add to cart", {item: "name", price: 120.00}. The 120.00 is a float The back end requires both value and data type.

However, the JavaScript intrinsic changes 120.00 from float to int and since we cannot know the data type from beforehand we are passing the wrong data type to the backend.

I am looking for some type of insight as to how to maintain the Data and its type in JavaScript sdk. Eg.

```
smartech('dispatch', 'myEvent', {price: 115.00});
// this line of code executed by client and 
// we don't have control over the value of price and data type
function dispatch(event, payload) {
 // event = myEvent
 // payload = {price: 115.00} 
 /* in this price attribute is a float send by a client but gets converted to integer by JavaScript we need the datatype to be maintained by JS as our backend required datatype, or it breaks
 */

 /* 
    Business logic : send data to backend
 */

 var promise = new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    /*if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     resolve(true);
    } else {
     reject(false);
    }*/
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "backendURL", payload);
  xhttp.send();
 });
}
```

How can I maintain a datatype of payload while accepting data to my function. As my backend strictly depends on datatype.

I have tried this on browser console also

```
var a = 210.00;
console.log(a);
```

in console i got 210 which is integer.

since expected to my backend is float but i am getting int value , so my backend is discarding those calls.I know this is very corner case but i need to handle it globally.

Comment: What does this do? `a.toFixed(2);`?

Comment: Also "backend required datatype, or it breaks" is a bad design.

Comment: this convert number to string

Comment: yes i know but this how it was designed and now its not possible to change architecture

Comment: yes, in JS if the number does not have any decimals its converted to int. That's the normal behavior. What you can do is, when you have to pass the data to your backend use the `.toFixed(2)` to make sure the number at least has 2 fractions in place.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but again toFixed changed its datatype to string which is also not allowed to my system

Comment: When you pass data via http, its converted to string. It does not preserve the datatype.

Comment: Can you show the error you get when you pass the data to the server?

Comment: there is no such error got, it is the logic they have implemented.i have java application which stores the data in vertica. and end point mentioned in ajax provides the data to java application which check say price payload was defined as float but he is receiving int then it just discard the change and srore the price as null

Comment: Did you debug by passing a string like `"29.99"`? Check if passing a string like this is discarded by the server. Its definitely not the data type that is the issue. Because http payload has no mechanism to preserve the data type.

Comment: ok.. let me check as it has impact on my dashboard which consume vertica data too and having calculations

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **parseFloat** and **toFixed** to maintain 2 decimal after point

```js
var a = parseFloat(210.00).toFixed(2);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: This makes no difference in the output.

Comment: @Chin.Udara , yeah it will not change output but it maintain datatype which was issue so now type will be float

and in parseFloat if we parse .00 , so parseFloat skip the .00 thats why i put toFixed 

if you check 210.03 with only parseFloat you will get output 210.03 
Hope you got my point

Comment: thanks but in my case price is not fixed sometimes it might float sometime int  so i just want to maintain its data type as it is

Comment: It still makes no sense to use parseFloat(210.03). Your answer will first parseFloat and then add decimal points, which in turn gives a string. Maybe you want to do `parseFloat((210).toFixed(2));` Notice the paranthesis around `210.toFixed(2)` However, the point is data type is NOT PRESERVED when you pass the data over http.

Comment: A programming language that does not respect types, and makes assumptions about math has unpredictable effects. Converting a float to an int automatically is a big no-no for me. It probably was fine when JavaScript was primarily used to render pages and UIs, but not okay when it's used for a backend. I would consider this a flaw in the programming language. Making assumptions about math and displaying numbers in a nice way should be left to the developer writing the code, not be part of the language specification.